# chrome packaged app widgets

Tags: widget, google-chrome-app

I am making a chrome packaged app.  I am partial to the dojo widget library.

Apparently, dojo doesn't run on chrome packaged apps.  Is there a javascript library that has a good widget set that is officially sanctioned by Google?

Thanks.  Rick

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure what "officially sanctioned" means, but I have had good luck with jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

I personally am a big fan of [UIKit](http://getuikit.com). Works wonderfully in Chrome packaged apps (Legacy and Chrome apps)